# Plot multiple histograms based on dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

I have a dataframe that is like this:

```
Client   Model_1      Model_2      Model_3    Model_4      Model_5
        1       10.34        0.22        0.62        0.47         1.96
        2        0.97        0.60        0.04        0.78         0.19
        3        2.01        0.15        0.27        0.49         0.00
        4        0.57        0.94        0.11        0.66         0.00
        5        0.68        0.65        0.26        0.41         0.50
        6        0.55        3.59        0.06        0.01         5.50
        7       10.68        1.08        0.07        0.16         0.20
```

And i need to plot a histogram for each of this clients(one histogram per line).
I've tried to use ggplot2 with cowplot, but didn't worked out very well(I'm new to R), so if anyone could help me i would be thankfull!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Code
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Client) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',aes(fill=factor(Client)))+
  facet_wrap(.~Client,scales = 'free')
```

Output:

[image]

In this case you would need a bar plot. Or this for histogram:

```
#Code 2
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Client) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=value))+
  geom_histogram(aes(fill=factor(Client)))+
  facet_wrap(.~Client,scales = 'free')
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Client = 1:7, Model_1 = c(10.34, 0.97, 2.01, 0.57, 
0.68, 0.55, 10.68), Model_2 = c(0.22, 0.6, 0.15, 0.94, 0.65, 
3.59, 1.08), Model_3 = c(0.62, 0.04, 0.27, 0.11, 0.26, 0.06, 
0.07), Model_4 = c(0.47, 0.78, 0.49, 0.66, 0.41, 0.01, 0.16), 
    Model_5 = c(1.96, 0.19, 0, 0, 0.5, 5.5, 0.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: This is awesome, but could you explain me more about the code?

Comment: @ArturBraga Sure, mainly you reshape the data to long using pivot longer, then you take two paths, you can use geom_bar or geom_hist. The key is that you want each row plotted so those options can be useful. Let me know if anything is not clear for you :)

Comment: In my actual program i have 30 clients, so 30 plots in one page gets pretty messy(visualy), is there a way to "multi-page" this plots?

Comment: @ArturBraga Try this in the end `facet_wrap(.~Client,scales = 'free',nrow = 6,ncol = 5)`

Comment: Can I place a label/legend to describe the models, like the clients?

Comment: Just do this change for fill `fill=name`

Comment: There is no way to keep both? i just wanted to place a description, manually...

Comment: Try with `fill=interaction(name,Client)`

Comment: I didn't worked, but thanks for everything, I'll try to figure out this myself